# Angular 5 cannot connect ImageCropperComponent to its components

Tags: angular, typescript

I installed the package ["ngx-image-cropper"](https://github.com/web-dave/ngx-img-cropper)
The structure of my project is as follows

- App
- App -> Pages
- App -> Pages -> Page 1 -> Component1
- App -> Pages -> Page 2 -> Component2

If I connect the cropper to **Component1** then everything works
I import The ImageCropperComponent component into **Page1.module.ts**
But now I need to work in **Component2** cropper. Removing import from Page1.module.ts, I add it to the module above, that is, in **Page.module.ts**.
And my app stops seeing him.

Console.log

```
  Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'image' since it isn't a known property of 'img-cropper'.
1. If 'img-cropper' is an Angular component and it has 'image' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'img-cropper' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("ex justify-content-center text-center"
```

I tried to install and ImageCropperModule in the App.module.ts and Page.module.ts without results, get the same error.
How do I install cropper for my components? What is my mistake?

My page.module.ts

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PagesComponent } from './pages.component';
import { PagesRoutingModule } from './pages-routing.module';
import { ThemeModule } from '../@theme/theme.module';
import { NewsModule} from './news/news.module';
import {ImageCropperComponent} from 'ngx-img-cropper';
const PAGES_COMPONENTS = [
  PagesComponent,
    ImageCropperComponent,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    PagesRoutingModule,
    ThemeModule,
      NewsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...PAGES_COMPONENTS,
  ],
})
export class PagesModule {
}
```

My component2.component.html (This code is also used in other components)

```
<img-cropper class="croppedBlock d-flex justify-content-center text-center"
                                     *ngIf="cropperVisible" [image]="data1" [settings]="cropperSettings1"
                                     (onCrop)="boundInfo($event)"></img-cropper>
                        <div class="resultCropper">
                      <span class=" imageCropper" *ngIf="data1.image">
                        <img *ngIf="savedImage" [src]="data1.image">
                            </span>
                            <button class="btn {{classButtonCropper}} d-block mb-2 mt-2 ml-auto mr-auto"
                                    (click)="cropped(bounds)" *ngIf="statusCropped" [innerHtml]="statusCropped">
                            </button>
                        </div>
```

**Decision**
Remove ImageCropperComponent from parent module and import ImageCropperModule to each parent module where It will be used

Comment: Can you show your code for your `page.module.ts` files?

Comment: If it is module, why you do not add it to imports : [ImageCorpperModule]?
And you also will not need to add the ImageCropperComponent to the list because this would be registered in your ImageCropperModule

Comment: @LkPark If you add an ImageCropperModule to import, the console shows that I am trying to connect the same component twice (ImageCropperComponent). If you remove ImageCropperComponent from declarations, I get the previous error

Comment: @IlyaFrolov Then there is a problem with your module, can you add some snippets of your NgModule(ImageCropper)?

Comment: @LkPark Where can I see this? ImageCropper I downloaded from GitHub

Comment: @IlyaFrolov Add the part of html where you use it.

Answer (score 2):

This should look like this.

page.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PagesComponent } from './pages.component';
import { ImageCropperModule } from 'ngx-img-cropper';

const PAGES_COMPONENTS = [
  PagesComponent
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ImageCropperModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...PAGES_COMPONENTS,
  ],
})
export class PagesModule {}
```

page.component.ts

```
import { CropperSettings } from 'ngx-img-cropper';

@Component({
    selector: 'page',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
    templateUrl: './page.component.html'
})
export class PageComponent {

    public data: any;
    public cropperSettings: CropperSettings;

    constructor() {

        this.cropperSettings = new CropperSettings();
        this.cropperSettings.width = 100;
        this.cropperSettings.height = 100;
        this.cropperSettings.croppedWidth = 100;
        this.cropperSettings.croppedHeight = 100;
        this.cropperSettings.canvasWidth = 400;
        this.cropperSettings.canvasHeight = 300;

        this.data = {};
    }
}
```

page.component.html

```
<img-cropper [image]="data" [settings]="cropperSettings"></img-cropper><br>
<img [src]="data.image" [width]="cropperSettings.croppedWidth" [height]="cropperSettings.croppedHeight">
```

Comment: I did what you wrote. Created a file in the page directory called image-cropper.module.ts added ImageCropperComponent to it and tried to import the new module into page.module.ts. The error persists

Comment: Oh no, this was just example, I thought this is some custom module. I will try to boot it for my self and let you know if there are some problems.

Comment: This changes I made are applied to my personal project I got the upload button and the crop is working as expected, try to make the same changes, make sure no other place module is loaded, only the PageModule for now.

Comment: I have in the page.coponent.ts is
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

Comment: There is some miss configuration, I would suggest you to setup it from beginning, just try to have the same setup, because your error message tells that module is not loaded properly. But all I can say that the only part required for boot is to import the ImageCropperModule and that's all. The rest is straightforward with cropper settings.